# Showing form 2 before form 1

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have this VB.NET program that I wrote in Windows Visual Studio 2010 and there are two forms. The `form1` will go first before `form2` but now I changed my mind and I want `form2` to load first when I open my program before `form1`. I have tried a lot of troubleshooting but no luck `form1` is still loading first.

Comment: In `Main()` method call your form1 like `Application.Run(form1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double click on My Project in Solution Explorer. There you can set the Startup form to form2.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you have a straightforward windows forms project that does not have a sub main procedure (you should read up about sub main procedures as with that you could follow the advice in the in the comment below your question).

For your problem you need to click on 'My Project' in the solution explorer and then open up (if it doesn't open by default) the application tab.  There are three drop down controls on the left hand side of the tab the last of which is 'Startup Object'.  Under this you will find 'Form2'.  Select that and your application will start with form 2 rather than form 1.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the project menu and click " Properties" (the bottom option). In the tab that opens, change the drop down list labelled "Startup Form" to whichever form you want to show first.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The following steps may help out:

1. Click on form1, go to its Topmost property and set it to false.
2. Click on form2, go to its Topmost property and set it to true.
3. Double click on form1 and write the following code:

```
   me.hide()
   form2.show()
```

4. Double click on form2 and write the following code:

```
   me.show()
   form1.hide()
```

I have tried and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Please navigate on solution Explorer and click program.cs then change Application.Run(new nameoftheformyouwanttostartwith());

on where its written name of the for you want to start it then enter then name

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).